# Why does this USB device not autosuspend?

Tags: linux, usb, powertop

Running `powertop` and tabbing over to "Device stats", I see 100% usage - which means no autosuspend - for "USB device: usb-device-8087-0a2a".

Googling this ID tells me it is a bluetooth device.  Or looking in sysfs.

```
$ cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3  # i don't know the logic to this
$ cat idVendor
8087
$ cat idProduct 
0a2a
$ readlink driver */driver
../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usb
../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/btusb
../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/btusb
```

The driver supports autosuspend.  However the device that contains the btusb endpoints is considered used.

```
$ cd power
$ cat level
auto
$ cat autosuspend
2
$ cat runtime_active_kids 
0
$ cat runtime_usage
1
```

This is despite me having no active bluetooth sockets

```
$ netstat -a
...
Active Bluetooth connections (servers and established)
Proto  Destination       Source            State         PSM DCID   SCID      IMTU    OMTU Security
Proto  Destination       Source            State     Channel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo lsof +D /dev/bus/usb
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
fwupd   2186 root   28u   CHR  189,2      0t0 11356 /dev/bus/usb/001/003
```

The USB device was being held open by fwupd.  This defect should be fixed [in the next released version](https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/issues/77#issuecomment-270465055).